# Using UrlFetch With Static IP Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api, google-workspace

I am currently building a Slack program. I have several of the functions in my google scripts. I need to use a Incoming Webhook. With Slack however that has to be a static dns url (unless I am mistaken?) I want to use UrlFetch, but it comes from a different IP according to my tests. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I don't see where Slack's documentation lists this requirement and I'm fairly certain I've called their webhooks previously without issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a static IP address for using Slack's [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks). Slack will accept requests from any IP address to the given webhook URL, even from `localhost`.